# Hyperlink button breaks some URLs when automatically undoing URL encoding

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

### Background

As of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-) feature request being completed, links pasted into the **Insert Hyperlink** dialog that appears when you click the Hyperlink button in the editor automatically go through some kind of URL-encoding, replacing non-ascii and certain other characters with [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) versions. For example, if you paste

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_strip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip)

into the hyperlink box and click `OK`, the link that gets inserted into the editor is actually a link to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip

This percent-*encoding* of characters works fine, and, as far as I know, does not break anything. However...

### Bug

The **Insert Hyperlink** box also - destructively and, as far as I can tell, pointlessly -  ***un-encodes*** certain characters in URLs, notably including the ampersand and equals signs, which many sites require to be percent-encoded when appearing as part of the data in a query string. That is, occurrences of `%26` or `%3D` in URLs pasted into the **Insert Hyperlink** box are replaced with `&` and `=` respectively.

Examples of this breaking, or else undesirably modifying, links:

**1)** This valid Google search URL:

[https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stackoverflow+q%26a](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=q%26a)

gets converted to this rather differently-behaving one if you paste it into the **Insert Hyperlink** box:

[https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stackoverflow%20q&a](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=q&a)

**2)** This valid URL from developers.facebook.com:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me()

gets converted to this broken one:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20=%20me%28%29

### Proposed Solution

Never un-encode any percent-encoded characters in a URL pasted into the Hyperlink box, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this a while ago, see [Different HTML from inline and numbered Markdown links breaks links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258611/different-html-from-inline-and-numbered-markdown-links-breaks-links) on Meta.SO.